# Pointers' array in a function does not showing on the correct values of the array used in call

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

double getAverage(int *arr[], int size) { 
    int i, sum = 0; 
    double avg; 

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    { 
        printf("%d %d\n", i, arr[i]);
        sum = sum + arr[i]; 
    }    
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    avg = (double)sum / size; 
    return avg; 
}

int main () 
{ 
    /* an int array with 5 elements */ 
    int balance[5] = {1000, 2, 3, 17, 50}; 
    double avg; 
    /* pass pointer to the array as an argument */ 
    avg = getAverage( balance, 5 ) ; 
    /* output the returned value */ 
    printf("Average value is: %f\n", avg ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

It's output is not correct. When I print the *arr[] values, the are not the same as the balance value. Do you know why and how I can fix this program?

```
0 1000                                                                                                                                                         
1 3                                                                                                                                                            
2 50                                                                                                                                                           
3 0                                                                                                                                                            
4 0                                                                                                                                                            
256992                                                                                                                                                         
Average value is: 51398.400000
```

Comment: `int *arr[]` -> `int arr[]`, your compiler should have warned you, compile with all warnings enabled

Comment: @Jabberwocky Is it wrong to use pointer array in the function? Because I want to have that.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong, read the answers below. And no, you don't want that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is declared like

```
double getAverage(int *arr[], int size)
```

That is, the first argument is supposed to be an array of *pointers* to `int`.

Then you call it as

```
getAverage( balance, 5 )
```

where `balance` is an array of `int`, which decays to a pointers to its first element (i.e. `balance` is equal to `&balance[0]`). This have the type `int *`.

The two types are mismatching, which the compiler should have warned you about.

The solution is to fix the function argument:

```
double getAverage(int *arr, int size)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
double getAverage(int *arr[], int size) {
```

You're passing a pointer to an array. That decays to a double pointer (a `int**`). You're using it like an `int*`, however. As a result, the pointer arithmetic under the hood is wrong. Change it to this:

```
double getAverage(int arr[], int size) {
```

It looks like on your setup, the pointers are twice as big as your ints, which is why it's always skipping a value (and ends up accessing invalid memory in the end).

If your compiler did not issue any warning for this code, try to see if you can set it to be more strict with warnings.